# error: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c

I wanted to do a scan chain in following order but I face to an error : 
    error: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
What is wrong with my assignments?

```
/****************************************************/
void * x1_in[1024];
int x_out[1024];
double a1, a2;

for (k=0; k<init_num; k++) {
    a1 = *(x1_in + k);
    a2 = *(x1_in + (k+1));
    x_out[k] = a1 + a2;
}
/****************************************************/
```

Comment: You need to cast the `void` pointers before derefernecing them. And is there a reason you use pointer arithmetic instead of plain array indexing (i.e. `x1_in[k]`)? Actually, that tells me of another problems you have, because `x1_in` is an array of pointer, doing `x1_in[k]` (which is equal to `*(x1_in + k)`) will give you a *pointer*, which you try to assign to a `double` variable.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`void * x1_in[1024];` is a pointer to an array which is equal to a pointer, so you have a pointer to a pointer.

Dereferencing `a1 = *(x1_in +k);` returns a pointer, you need `a1 = *(double*)(x1_in +k);`

Comment: This results in dereferencing a void pointer, which is not valid.

Comment: `x1_in` is an array of pointers, not *"a pointer to an array"*.